# Удалить лишние символы в list python

Tags: python, mysql, sqlite, list

мне нужно записывать данные из txt в sqlite3.
С этим я разобрался

```py
print("Введите полную ссылку к txt файлу, например D:\\Codding\\Work\\Python ")
Ab = input("Введите сюда ")

con = sqlite3.connect("D:\\Codding\\Work\\Python\Works\\Bot for searching\\base.bd")
curs = con.cursor()
blb = open(Ab, 'r', encoding='utf-8')

file_data = [i.strip('\n').split(';') for i in blb]



curs.executemany('INSERT INTO dann_Vk VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)', file_data )
con.commit()
print("Успешно")
```

Также мне нужно, чтобы в одном столбце удалялись автоматом лишние символы, например везде записаны номера вот так: (8)9765431271
А в базу записывалось вот так: 89765431271

Как это реализовать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

как вариант

```
import re
oldstr = "(8)324729472"
newstr = re.sub('[()]', '', oldstr)
print(newstr)
```

вот может поможет:

```
file_data = [re.sub('[()]', '', i).strip('\n').split(';') for i in blb]
```

Comment: А как сделать, что бы так выполнялось со всеми строками, допустим у меня 17000 строк в таком формате
(8)38931939,Имя,Фамилия \n
(8)38941939,Имя,Фамилия \n
(8)38931939,Имя,Фамилия \n

Comment: пробежать циклом по строкам файла и удалить символы, можно конечно еще регулярное выражение написать для поиска в фале номеров по формату и тогда изменить, вариантов масса

Comment: Как тогда цикл устроить если это список, Если вот так пробовать, получается ошибка: for i in file_data:
    c = re.sub('[()]', '', str(file_data) )
    print(c)
    curs.execute("""INSERT INTO dann VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)""", c  )
    con.commit()
    print("Успешно")
Incorrect number of bindings supplied. The current statement uses 5, and there are 249 supplied.

Comment: file_data = [re.sub('[()]', '', i).strip('\n').split(';') for i in blb]

Comment: Спасибо! А если хочется также удалит например "-" как?

Comment: Или пробел лишний